# Homeomorphisms between two punctured planes

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

**Question**:

> Let $p,q$ be two different points in the interior of $D\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ where $D$ is the closed unit disk. Is there a homeomorphism $h:\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{p\}\to\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{q\}$ such that $h|_{\partial D}=id_{\partial D}$?

---

This question is motivated by the following exercise:

> Let $D\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ be the closed unite disk $\{x\in\Bbb{R}^2\mid \|x\|=1\} $ and $f:D\to\Bbb{R}^2$ a continuous map such that $f|_{\partial D}=id_{\partial D}$. Show that $D\subset f(D)$.

which looks very similar to the following ones:

[Continuous function from the closed unit disk to itself being identity on the boundary must be surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171451/9464)

[Let $f : D \rightarrow D$ be a continuous map whose restriction to $S^1$ is the identity map. Show that $f$ must be surjective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425082/9464)

I tried to adapt the techniques in the answers to those two questions and came up with the  question above that  I don't really see how to go on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider a cone $C$ that intersects the plane in $\partial D$ and with vertex $t$. Then the projection along the line $tp$  gives us a homeomorphism $C\to\Bbb R^2$ with $t\mapsto p$; the same can be done with $t\mapsto q$. Combine these (and remove the points $p,t,q$):

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you elaborate "the projection along the line $tp$"?

Comment: @Jack: I think you will find it helpful to draw a picture for this; the construction is not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a non-self intersecting path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ from $p$ to $q$ such that $\dot \gamma(t)\not=0$. Extend the $\dot \gamma$ to a vector field in a small neighborhood of the curve. Using a bumpfunction extend this vector field to a compactly supported vector field in the interior of $D$. The flow of this vector field at time $1$ will give you the required homeomorphism (diffeo even), as $\gamma$ is a solution curve. Note that you can extend this idea to many points, and also on other higher dimensional manifolds.